# Show that function is greater than a value, subject to a constraint.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove that if $\max\{|x|,|y|\} > 10$, then $f(x, y) > 1000$, where $f(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 - 2xy$

I am attempting to use the Method of Lagrange Multipliers.

However $\max\{|x| ,|y|\} > 10$ I believe is not bounded, and so I am unsure how to proceed here.

Comment: That's a rather loose bound to prove for $\,f(x,y)=x^2(x^2-1)+y^2(y^2-1)+(x-y)^2\,$.

Comment: Hint: $\max\{|x| ,|y|\} = \frac{1}{2} (|x| + |y| + | |x| - |y| |)$

Comment: I am struggling to determine how the rewritten version helps @-dxiv

Comment: Also, when we write out max{|x|,|y|} explicitly, can we use Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: @ColourFulPlane Assume WLOG that $\,|x| \gt 10\,$ then $\,x^2(x^2-1) \gt 9900\,$. Now look at the other terms and find/prove some bounds for those.